# T sql order by 2 rows according to different dates

Tags: sql-server

I have table called "**customers**"

**customers** table has below columns

```
CompanyName varchar(100)    
ProductName varchar(100)    
CreatedDate datetime    
Salesprice money
```

I have below data in **customer** table

```
CompanyName (column) - ProductName (column)  -  CreatedDate (column) -   Salesprice (column)
A                      B                        2015-01-02 00:00:00.000  419,10      
C                      D                        2014-04-20 00:00:00.000  30,10       
A                      B                        2014-01-02 00:00:00.000  60,00       
C                      D                        2015-04-20 00:00:00.000  540,00
```

I want to select data as below. I need to order by CreatedDate from less than more like

```
CreatedDate 2014

CreatedDate 2015

CreatedDate 2014

CreatedDate 2015
```

Result must be as below (2014-2015 ordering)

```
A                      B                  2014-01-02 00:00:00.000  60,00  (This is 2014)
A                      B                  2015-01-02 00:00:00.000  419,10 (This is 2015)    
C                      D                  2014-04-20 00:00:00.000  30,10  (This is 2014)  
C                      D                  2015-04-20 00:00:00.000  540,00 (This is 2015)
```

**Question:**

How can i select customer table

**First 2014 date than 2015 date if exists more then 2016 etc..** if **CompanyName** is same and **ProductName** is **Same** like **Result** in above side ?

Comment: your question is unclear @_@

Comment: Parts of your question read as if some filtering is required but then you also give sample data and your expected result contains exactly the same number of results - so is there some filtering needed here and if so, can you expand the sample data to demonstrate that?

Comment: I need to order by 2014 than 2015 not 2014-2014-2015-2015

Comment: @wewesthemenace i need to order by 2 dates per 2 rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is add ORDER BY in your query.

```
SELECT * from customers
ORDER BY CompanyName, ProductName, CreatedDate;
```

UPDATED:

```
SELECT  CompanyName, ProductName, CreatedDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(CreatedDate) 
                                  ORDER BY YEAR(CreatedDate)) as rownumber
FROM    customers
ORDER by rownumber, YEAR(CreatedDate)
```